# Call three projects from onther project,Java

Tags: java, netbeans, merge

I want to ask something. I have done three small projects on Java at Netbeans. Can I make a project which it calls theese three projects ? I want to have all theese projects in one programm. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes.

Expand the "master" project and right click on the "Libraries" node.

From the popup, select "Add Project".  Browse to the location of the project you want to link and select "Add Project JAR Files".

The project will now be linked to your project and you should be able to access it's classes.

Note, if the child project has any dependencies of it's own, you will need to add those to the "master" project as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add those projects into your new program build path or make the libraries and use it.